# Retrieve custom order item meta data values in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, orders

I have the following code which is creating cart Item data based on some custom fields:

```
function parcel_add_shipment_text_to_cart_item( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) { 

$service = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'servicelevel' );
$servicecode = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'servicecode'); 
$price = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'sellprice' );
$chargeweight = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'chargeweight' );  

$cart_item_data['servicelevel'] = $service;
$cart_item_data['servicecode'] = $servicecode;
$cart_item_data['serviceprice'] = $price;
$cart_item_data['chargeweight'] = $chargeweight;

return $cart_item_data; }


add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'parcel_add_shipment_text_to_cart_item', 10, 3 );
```

Then I add the cart meta here:

```
function add_custom_field_text_to_order_items( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {


$item->add_meta_data( __( 'Service Level', 'Shipment' ), $values['servicelevel'] );
$item->add_meta_data( __( 'Your Reference', 'Shipment' ), $values['shipmentref'] );
$item->add_meta_data( __( 'Sell Price', 'Shipment' ), $values['serviceprice'] );
$item->add_meta_data( __( 'Charge Weight', 'Shipment' ), , $values['chargeweight'] );  } 

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'add_custom_field_text_to_order_items', 10, 4 );
```

How do I retrieve the above Item meta data to be used in the woocommerce_payment_complete or order complete screen? I know the above data is working as I can see it on the order screen and email. Your help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using your custom order item meta data in woocommerce_payment_complete action hook (or in any other hook where you can get the order ID or the order object):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'on_action_payment_complete', 10, 1 );
function on_action_payment_complete( $order_id ) {
    // Get an instance of the WC_Order Object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Loop through order items
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ){
        $servicelevel = $item->get_meta('Service Level');
        $servicecode  = $item->get_meta('Your Reference');
        $serviceprice = $item->get_meta('Sell Price');
        $chargeweight = $item->get_meta('Charge Weight');
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works. The code inside the hook is tested and really works.

Comment: Hey Loic, I have a question if you don't mind. You know how Woocommerce displays meta data in a certain way when doing the following. How do I stop it displaying it in order etc but keep the meta data added?                                     $item->add_meta_data( __( 'Service Level', 'Shipment' ), $values['servicelevel'] );